# Transparent ActionBarCompat drawer integrated with GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-actionbar-compat

I have a strange behavior of navigation drawer when I use **ActionBarCompat** + **GoogleMaps** on **Android 2.x** The problem is not completely hide GoogleMap fragment when navigation drawer is opened.

The normal state of application you can see on the next screen. Navigation drawer is closed and GoogleMaps is shown.

[image: Normal state. Drawer closed]

When I open the drawer you can see on screen below that only zoom buttons, google label and locate me buttons are hided.

[image: invalid behavior]

I have an opposite behavior of screen as soon I take a screenshot. When screenshot has taken, android refresh all views and I see valid view.

[image: valid behavior]

You can download the project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5854374/com.example.zip).

By the way, application is working well on Android 4.x. The issue occurred only on Android 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably related to the fact, on Android 4.0 and below `SurfaceView` is used, when on Android 4.1+ there is a `TextureView`.

In my demo project I fixed it by overlaying transparent `View` over the `SupportMapFragment` like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You may see how it works [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo).

Comment: It works for my and looks so simple but it took a few days of me :) Thank you so much!